# getting labels from the dataframe not working properly

Tags: r

I want to get labels from the data dynamically, for example dfl2, it should fetch "All","Media","BT","Team B" etc. and same as for for dfl1 should be "All", "Media", "BT" etc. and also for dfl3.

Its perfectly working if i give banner definition like below like below

```
dfl1 <- c("all","vs1","am1")
labels <- names(sapply(dfl1, function(x) {df[x] %>%  val_lab()}))
```

but i want to give banner definition like below, it should work for below

```
dfl3 <- list(df$all,df$vs1,df$carb1)
```

```r
library(expss)     
df <- mtcars 
d1 <- sapply(df1, function(x) names(val_lab(x)))[names(dfl1)]

lapply(dfl2,function(x) {df[x] |> var_lab()})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a list with columns like this `dfl2 <- list(df$all,df$vs1,df$am1,df$gear1)` you lose all variable names. It's better to keep columns as a data frame: `dfl2 <- df[, c("all", "vs1", "am1","gear1")]`.

And second issue is `lapply(dfl2,function(x) {df[x] |> var_lab()})`. You pass to the function column values rather than column names. And column names don't have labels. This should work: `lapply(dfl2,var_lab)`.